# how timer count down in this example ? how date which represent new Date().getTime() is greater than nextDate ? could any one explain that pls?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, timer

how date is greater than nextDate ??

could any one explain clearly how this code works ?

```
  const controlTime = () => {
    let second = 1000
    let date = new Date().getTime()
    let nextDate = new Date().getTime() + second
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      date = new Date().getTime()
      if (date > nextDate) {  // how date is greater than nextDate ??
        setDisplayTime((prev) => {
          return prev - 1
        })
        nextDate += second  // how it will be as a result ???
      }
    }, 30)
  }
```

Comment: Find out what `setInterval()` does

Comment: in this example it updates interval every 30 seconds but how it does exactly inside ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the function `setDisplayTime` and the var `prev` aren't included in your code, so I can't explain that with accuracy, but I can infer from the function name that that it changes a display time somewhere in the UI.

However, for the other aspects of your question:
`date` will become greater than `nextDate` eventually because during the `setInterval` function the date variable is mutated or updated to the current time every 30 milliseconds (not seconds as you say in your comment, timers in JS work in milliseconds). The `nextDate` is only updated when the ever-increasing `date` variable then exceeds the current value stored in `nextDate`.

`nextDate += second` is a short hand increment calculation for `nextDate = nextDate + second`. This code adds one second (or 1000 milliseconds as set in the second varible) to `nextDate` and resets this same variable with the updated value. Thus making it once again greater than `date` and so our check runs again every 30 milliseconds and repeats for as long as the code is running.

Comment: Your explanation is pretty good, you saved my life :) . I appreciate a lot what you did for me.